Reactor Netty shutdown not processing remaining requests (executor not accepting a task)
I got a Java Spring Boot 3 reactive application and I found that, when the servers are being shutdown gracefully, some of the remaining requests (making external calls using WebClient) are failing due to exception:
IllegalStateException: executor not accepting a task

This exception seems to come from Netty and is thrown if executor.isShuttingDown().
Is there a way to make the application wait gracefully for all the existing Reactive requests to be completed before shutting down Netty?

May be you need to configure longer timeout? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/web/graceful-shutdown.html
